# Formatting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from mysql db using strotime and then output html

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql, I have a table that records the date when changes have been made using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for any given row. The format in the field is for example `2013-11-16 19:08:55`

I have the following query

```
$sql = "SELECT `title` ,  `lesson_id` ,  `description` ,  `category_id` ,  `img`, `date` FROM blog";
    $sqlBlog = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $sqlBlog->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $title = $row['title'];
        $url = $row['lesson_id'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $category = $row['category_id'];
        $dateRow = $row['date'];
}
```

What I want to do is take $dateRow and explode it in to

```
$explode = explode('-', $date);

foreach ($explode as $var)
{
    echo'<span>'.$var.'</span>';
}
```

The problem is the formatting is 2013-11-16 HH:ii:ss and I wanted it as 16 Nov 13. I can't seem to convert the date in the mysql db using strotime.

```
$date = strtotime($dateRow);
date_format($date, 'd-M-y');
```

but then I get the error `date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, integer given`

not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you can't you just go:

```
echo date('d M y', strtotime($dateRow)); //16 Nov 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use date() function instead of the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

Ok after your comment;

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01 00:00:00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: current_timestamp is the default in the DB... I'm not running any date functions to update that information. MYSQL automatically sets the date whenever there's an update to the table without having to rely on an UPDATE or INSERT from a php script. The point is that in the DB it's stored as a string which I need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime($dateRow);
 echo $date->format('d M y');
```

This should give what you are seeking

Comment: I've tried that along with `date_create` but I get object of class could not be converted to string.

Comment: Perhaps you should use explicit catsting, something like:
$date = new DateTime((string) $dateRow);

Answer (score 0):

Use date(format, timestamp) function or simply

```
$date = strtotime($dateRow);
echo date('d M y',$date);
```